# Calendar range picker in React Native

Tags: ios, datepicker, reactjs, react-native

I was wondering if any of you knew of a calendar picker or calendar range picker, similar to the one found in the Kayak app in IOS.   There you have two input fields for a round trip and when you select either one you can see the dates selected.
[image: The two input fields]

[image: The calendar picker]

Does any of you know whether something similar to this is available for React Native ?  I have taken a look at [this calendar picker](https://github.com/stephy/CalendarPicker) but it does not allow for a range select, nor a min or max date which would be ideally.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Here is a range picker,I haven't used it but does allow for ranges... https://github.com/werein/react-native-dates

Answer (score 0):

Another date range picker:

https://github.com/ivanchenko/react-native-day-picker

Also there's a branch here, at the time of writing this, that implemented date multi-select.

https://github.com/jdmunro/react-native-calendar/tree/multi-select